# Error building Custom Sitemap

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

I'm trying to build a custom sitemap
I look into code on this site

http://harriyott.com/2007/03/adding-dynamic-nodes-to-aspnet-site

I have convert it into vb.net as far as I could

here is my code

```
Partial Class Main

Inherits StaticSiteMapProvider

Dim conn As New ConnectionVB
Dim _rootNode As SiteMapNode = Nothing
Dim _siteMapFileName As String
Dim SiteMapNodeName As String = "siteMapNode"

Public Sub DynamicSiteMapProvider()
End Sub

Public Shadows Function RootNode() As SiteMapNode
    Return BuildSiteMap()
End Function

Public Overrides Sub Initialize(name As String, attributes As NameValueCollection)
    //Me.Initialize(name, attributes)
    _siteMapFileName = attributes("siteMapFile")
End Sub

Protected Overrides Function GetRootNodeCore() As SiteMapNode
    Return RootNode()
End Function

Protected Overrides Sub clear()
    SyncLock Me
        _rootNode = Nothing
        //Me.clear()
    End SyncLock
End Sub

Public Overrides Function BuildSiteMap() As SiteMapNode
    SyncLock Me
        If _rootNode Is Nothing Then
            clear()
            Dim siteMapXml As XmlDocument = LoadSiteMapXml()
            Dim rootElement As XmlElement = CType(siteMapXml.GetElementsByTagName(SiteMapNodeName)(0), XmlElement)
            AddDynamicNodes(rootElement)
            GenerateSiteMapNodes(rootElement)
        End If
    End SyncLock
    Return _rootNode
End Function

Private Function LoadSiteMapXml() As XmlDocument
    Dim siteMapXml As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
    siteMapXml.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + _siteMapFileName)
    Return siteMapXml
End Function

Protected Sub AddDynamicNodes(rootElement As XmlElement)
    Dim teams As XmlElement = AddDynamicChildElement(rootElement, "", "FootballTeams", "List of football team")
End Sub

Protected Function AddDynamicChildElement(parentElement As XmlElement, url As String, title As String, description As String) As XmlElement
    Dim childElement As XmlElement = parentElement.OwnerDocument.CreateElement(SiteMapNodeName)
    childElement.SetAttribute("url", url)
    childElement.SetAttribute("title", title)
    childElement.SetAttribute("description", description)

    parentElement.AppendChild(childElement)
    Return childElement
End Function

Protected Sub GenerateSiteMapNodes(rootElement As XmlElement)
    _rootNode = GetSiteMapNodeFromElement(rootElement)
    AddNode(_rootNode)
    CreateChildNodes(rootElement, _rootNode)
End Sub

Protected Sub CreateChildNodes(parentElement As XmlElement, parentNode As SiteMapNode)
    For Each XmlElement As XmlNode In parentElement.ChildNodes
        If XmlElement.Name = SiteMapNodeName Then
            Dim childNode As SiteMapNode = GetSiteMapNodeFromElement(CType(XmlElement, XmlElement))
            AddNode(childNode, parentNode)
            CreateChildNodes(CType(XmlElement, XmlElement), childNode)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Protected Function GetSiteMapNodeFromElement(rootElement As XmlElement) As SiteMapNode
    Dim newSiteMapNode As SiteMapNode
    Dim url As String = rootElement.GetAttribute("url")
    Dim title As String = rootElement.GetAttribute("title")
    Dim description As String = rootElement.GetAttribute("description")

    newSiteMapNode = New SiteMapNode(Me, (url + title).GetHashCode().ToString(), url, title, description)
    Return newSiteMapNode
End Function

End Class
```

I got this kind of error

```
System.ArgumentException: Provider name cannot be null or empty.
```

I don't have any idea what the cause of this error
could someone help me??

Appreciate all help

thanks

PS : Sorry if my English messed up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that you have add this in web config.

```
<system.web>

    <siteMap defaultProvider="main">

        <providers>

            <add siteMapFile="Web.sitemap"  name="main" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider"/>

        </providers>

    </siteMap>
```

Comment: aw thanks that's really work!!! actually I have add it on my web.config but the type that I see on the example looks exactly like the name of his namespace and class...anyway thanks for one more time

Comment: mmm could you help me further??? I have do what you suggest and it works perfectly.. but now, this code didn't do anything..is there any mistake that I make??

Comment: you need to check your class and make sure that you have not missed something in converting it to vb. https://gist.github.com/harriyott/890963/raw/3eaa9aebcaba72a6e473913a238901615f08ce44/DynamicSiteMapProvider.cs

Comment: You need to then again set the type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" from to this class type="Harriyott.Web.DynamicSiteMapProvider"  as shown in the artical.

Comment: yeah I have miss 1 class..public DynamicSiteMapProvider(): base(){}. I don't know how to do that in vb.net...any suggestion??

Comment: use this online converter to convert c# to vb http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: thanks dude you really are helping me!! I want to ask once again..on that line of code,    SiteMapXml.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + _siteMapFileName), it throws an exception that it couldn't find the path..I have make sure that the path was the correct one..any suggestion?

Comment: site map file is on that path. if not then put it there. Save as this link with you site map file name https://gist.github.com/harriyott/a6babe4ed1652027d310/raw/e160a9949cd4026ceb72f2b3f7c13be118cce7b1/blog-2007-03-sitemap-1.xml and copy to that path.

Comment: please ask this problem in new question with updated code and exact error message. so other can also help you.